# How can I review the code affected by a specific changeset in Team System/TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, changeset

I've been all over the Visual Studio IDE and haven't been able to find where to see the itemized code/files affected by a specific changeset.

I found the Changeset option under "Find in source control..." option with the Source Control window up, but it's pretty useless at that point as it only lists the changeset for me but doesn't allow me to do anything with it after that.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the changeset in question hit Ctrl+G to open up the Find Changesets dialog.  If you know the changeset ID you can type it in the Changeset from,to section and press Find.  Then if you double-click the changeset you can view the files in it.  By right clicking on a file you can view it or compare it with another version.

Alternatively, use the [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) as [recommended by Joshua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034066/how-can-i-review-the-code-affected-by-a-specific-changeset-in-team-system-tfs/1035056#1035056).  They are very useful for many things - this included.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a really good place in the IDE to do that.  You have that option when you are merging changesets, or if a changeset has been associated with a work item (check the links tab).

Instead, I use [Team Foundation Sidekicks.](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/)  It's free and has a really simple code review module that lets you do exactly what you are asking for.

P.S.  I recommend this all the time, but, no I don't work for 'em.  I just use their tools several times a day.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at a list of changesets, such as clicking ViewHistory on a file or folder, you can just right-click the changeset you are interested in and select Details.
That should show you the files, checkin comments, attached workitems, etc.

Comment: But how do I get to a screen that'll let me enter the changeset to review? I've been given a changeset number but have no idea what items are in the changeset. So I see what you're saying for just clicking on any old file or folder, but I can't find where I can enter the changeset number and then get the details.